# How to hook RuntimeException to prevent crashes?

Tags: android, java, frida, exception

I tried to find out how [RuntimeException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException) works internally in [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/) so I can understand how to prevent crashes but didn't find anything useful and I have no clue how to analyze components-related JDK in perspective of reverse engineering, I'm curious what's going on behind [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) so I can prevent crashes

I tried with this Frida script but no luck

```js
Java.perform(function() {
    var RuntimeException = Java.use('java.lang.RuntimeException');
    RuntimeException.$init.overload().implementation = function(){
        console.log("hits .overload()")
        return;
    }
    
    RuntimeException.$init.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(arg1){
        console.log("hits .overload('java.lang.String')")
        return;
    }
    
    RuntimeException.$init.overload('java.lang.Throwable').implementation = function(arg1){
        console.log("hits .overload('java.lang.Throwable')")
        return;
    }
    
    RuntimeException.$init.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Throwable').implementation = function(arg1,arg2){
        console.log("hits .overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Throwable')")
        return;
    }
    
    RuntimeException.$init.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Throwable', 'boolean', 'boolean').implementation = function(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){
        console.log("hits .overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.Throwable', 'boolean', 'boolean')")
        return;
    }
    
})
```

Comment: @Robert then why when we try to patch `RuntimeException` calls the app is still crash when it calls `RuntimeException` ? is there someting happening internally ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RuntimeException` is an Exception class like all the others, the only difference is that developers are not forced to catch `RuntimeException` and its child classes. And there is no special relation between `RuntimeException` and "native calls" (JNI calls).

Your problems are independent of the `RuntimeException` instead they are located in your Frida hooking code:

When hooking an Java/Android method (or constructor) the Frida hook replaces the original function. So if you just want to log method/constructor calls you always have to manually execute the original method inside the hook.

At the moment you don't call the original constructor of `RuntimeException` and return nothing, which means if Android tries to create an instance of `RuntimeException` no exception instance is created. This can never happen in compiled Java code and in the end the app crashes.

Therefore you have to modify your hooking code to call the original constructor and return the created `RuntimeException` instance:

```
let RuntimeException = Java.use('java.lang.RuntimeException');
let RTctor1 = RuntimeException.$init.overload();
RTctor1.implementation = function() {
    console.log("hits .overload()");
    return RTctor1.call(this);
}
let RTctor2 = RuntimeException.$init.overload('java.lang.String');
RTctor2.implementation = function(arg0) {
    console.log("hits .overload('java.lang.String')");
    return RTctor2.call(this, arg0);
}
...
```

Comment: thank you Robert, but your hook code is only logging - actually it just makes the crash easier -, "you don't call the original constructor of RuntimeException and return nothing" -> this is the point to prevent [RuntimeException-based crashes](https://darvincitech.wordpress.com/2019/12/23/detect-frida-for-android/#comment-49). are these [cases](https://github.com/dqzg12300/fridaUiTools/blob/master/js/anti_debug.js#L137-L168) are not possible with RuntimeException ? and if not, why ?

Comment: @IVs OK, now I really understand what you are trying to do. But that can and will not work. If the app is crashing because of a RuntimeException that you can only try to hook the code and modify values/arguments in a way so that the exception is never thrown. If the app tries to throw an Exception it is already too late. Catching in exceptions in Frida e.g. by hooking a method that throws an Exception is also not that easy to my experience.